# Duvida na hora de retornar a quantidade de letras diferentes

Tags: ruby

Gostaria de retornar a quantidade de letras diferentes entre as duas strings, no caso nessa questão, as letras diferentes são `"TACG"` e `"ARGC"`, logo teria que retornar 4.

```
ruby def letras(string_1, string_2)
  contador = 0
  string_1 = string_1.split("")
  string_2 = string_2.split("")
  for letra in string_1
    for letra_1 in string_2
       if letra != letra_1
          contador += 1
       end
    end
  end
  return contador
end
puts letras 'GGTACGCAB', 'GGARGCAB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queria ver a se é a mesma letra em cada posição (index) da String:

```
def letras(string_1, string2)
  contador = 0
  string_1.split.each_with_index do |letra, index|
    counter += 1 if letra != string_2.split[index]
  end
  return contador
end
```